# I can't manage the shrinkwrap modifier to work even on a default subdivided default cube. What could possibly go wrong?

Tags: shrinkwrap

[image][image]I was trying the shrinkwrap modifier after watching a cloth reveal tutorial.

And I couldn't make it work on my object. Nothing happens when i apply the modifier and choose target object. After many failures i decided to wrap a default cube with no success.

I have no clues left.

After subdividing the plane i had some results but it's not shrinkwrap i guess.

Comment: Hello. Please add more details (pictures, modifiers settings, or share your blend file). As it is your question will hardly find an answer.

Comment: did you subdivide your plane? the more, the nicer the result. it is often the case when "nothing" happens. i forgot this often... ;)

Comment: I didn't. After subdividing I had some results but still not there yet. Added an image.

Comment: you should start with the manual page: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html?highlight=shrinkwrap